# different error page for Partial View

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I have a Error page with all Layout and Header, which works fine when error occured on the main View, it shows the error page correctly.
But when any error occured while rendering any partial view, it breaks the whole UI, because the error page also have Header,

So i wanted to know inside Global.asax (application_Error) that if the request is for partial view redirect it to  PartialError page else redirect it to Fullerror page.

Please let me know how can i achieve that.
thanks.

Comment: Are u render this partial by Ajax request?

Answer (score 2):

I suggest using filter attribute. You can implement something like this:

```
public class RedirectOnErrorAttribute : FilterAttribute, IExceptionFilter {

bool IsPartialRequest = false;

public void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext) {
        if(filterContext.ExceptionHandled) return;
        /*then you can redirect to a specific page or to, for example,
special error handling controller*/
         filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(new RouteValueDictionary(new { controller = "Error", action = "HandleError", isPartialError = IsPartialRequest }));
         filterContext.ExceptionHandled = true;
         filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Clear();
}
}
```

And in error handling controller in `HandleError` action method you can return specific View depending on the `isPartialError` parameter. BTW, you can do another useful things in this action method - for example log error info somehow.

To use this attribute you can decorate your controller classes with it:

```
[RedirectOnError]
public class MyController : Controller {

  public ViewResult Index () {}
  public ActionResult Create() {}

  [RedirectOnError(IsPartialRequest=true)]
  public PartialViewResult ListCategories() {}

}
```

pay attention to the attribute usage with `ListCategories` method - I explicitly told that this is the partial request. The reason I did it is simple - routing system  knows nothing about the fact that the result will be used as partial.